# Django Month archive view date_list has incorrect dates

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I am using django 1.5, python 3.3. The date_list in Month archive views is giving me incorrect dates.

In the documentation:

> A DateQuerySet object containing all days that have objects available in the given month, according to queryset, represented as datetime.datetime objects, in ascending order.

But i find it gives date which is a day before actual creation date. For example, a post is created on 9/7/2013. it shows 9/6/2013. is it because of some setting issue or something else?

Comment: I'd check your timezone settings. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: @Peter, the default is Chicago which is midwest, and i am in US Eastern time. It shouldnt make a big difference.

Comment: My concern is that one version of the date might be using UTC, so that the five-hour difference for US eastern time might matter. Checking the database's values through your SQL client should help either rule that out or confirm it, as should checking `is_aware` and `is_naive` on the date queryset results and observing exactly what gets recorded in the database if you create a post while it's later than midnight UTC. This is speculation, but it's a finicky subject in later versions of Django and seems a lot more likely to be responsible than random SQL errors.

Comment: @Peter, The datetime field in SQL is correct. Post.created shows the correct datetime, just the date_list doesnt. I will take a closer look and hopefully get it solved..Thanks a lot for your help.